# How to download emails through IMAP when uid and msgno can change

Tags: php, email, imap

I've written a small script that simply (as simple as email can be) downloads emails so I can play with them later. The part that I don't seem to be able to grasp quite perfectly is that the `msgno` can (will) change when new emails get added or emails get deleted. Okay, that's fine, but then for the `uid`, this also can (will) change when emails are moved from folder to folder.

So in PHP, for example, when I execute `imap_search` and get a list of `msgno`s or `uid`s, how do I reliably use these to get emails for a changing email box? In this example, there are multiple Outlook clients connected to this mailbox with many rules for auto-moving emails from/to specific people, etc. that's bound to move emails *after* I've already gotten the ID's, and *before* I actually get to processing that email.

In this case, what do you do? I would very much so like to avoid the email just "not existing" by the time I get to it, or worse, the ID in that IMAP mailbox be resigned to a new email.

Comment: UIDs *should* be internal to the IMAP server and constant across sessions. `msgno`s are simple sequence number that *should* be constant within a session. If they're not then that's a problem with your IMAP server, not PHP. If another client moves/deletes a message while your program is thinking, that's just too bad and you'll have to figure out how to handle the error. This is why multi-user mailboxes are an awful idea.

Comment: @Sammitch the same session would probably be fine, but downloading email bodies one at a time is so awfully slow, and the only way I've seemed to be able to get around this is by spawning separate php scripts that download bodies at the same time, but I'd have to pass those sub-scripts either the uid or msgno, so I don't know if I can keep the same session

Comment: @Sammitch it looks like threading might be the only way to do what I want to do

Comment: I'd only suggest threading if you need to do high-performance parallel processing on a single set of data. If you just need to handle a number of independent, serial processing jobs in a parallel fashion use a queue/worker model. eg: RabbitMQ and php-amqplib.

Comment: @Sammitch Hmm.. Looking into both solutions it doesn't really seem like this is possible in any sense. Even trying to share the IMAP resource to sub threads doesn't work, and then I dug even deeper and tried doing the IMAP connections manually myself using sockets but I obviously I can't make multiple requests on the same socket at the same time, which seems to be the core of my problem. I can't at all find a way that would seemingly be able to download multiple emails reliably from the email server at the same time.

Comment: You should be able to request more than one at once though, and the server can stream them to you.  This reduces latency waiting on roundtrips.  `tag UID FETCH 900:1000 (RFC822)`

Comment: @Max That definitely looks correct, it's a shame that the builtin PHP `imap_fetchbody` only supports single message IDs. For now I'm simply starting separate scripts with a `uid` that reconnects and downloads the body, and I just have to assume that the `uid` will never be reassigned by the web server. If the email moves in the mean time and it doesn't exist once I get to it that's fine, since another loop will pick it up, though

Comment: @Max maybe I'll revisit doing the IMAP connection manually without the builtins, I did find someone who goes into good depth about it with PHP, too https://www.toptal.com/php/building-an-imap-email-client-with-php